# Orbeon : linking ressources (css, images, js) leads to erratic behavior

Tags: orbeon

I'm developing a new webapp based on the orbeon samples. I'm using orbeon 3.9 CE. I got **VERY ERRATIC** behavior when I use custom ressources. They are placed in following folders :

```
/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/theme/*.css
/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/theme/*.js
/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/theme/images/*.jpg
```

In my custom theme file (/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/theme-xnotes.xsl), they are linked like this (a few examples) :

```
<xhtml:link rel="stylesheet" href="/config/theme/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<xhtml:script src="/config/theme/bootstrap.js"/>
<xhtml:link rel="icon" href="/config/theme/images/icone_grue.png" type="image/png"/>
```

When I point my browser at the application (http://localhost:8080/orbeon), it SOMETIMES work, SOMETIMES doesn't (css are ignored, page transitions are wrong) and SOMETIMES it works partially (css are ok, js not, a few images are ok, others are not and so on)

When I look at the page source code, the links seems to be ok, to take the sames examples as above :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/orbeon/config/theme/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="/orbeon/config/theme/bootstrap.js">
<link rel="icon" href="/orbeon/config/theme/images/icone_grue.png" type="image/png">
```

But some links are not valid and point to the root of the application. The main problem is that **I just can't make this behavior consistent** to isolate the issue(s).

Help really appreciated ! It's driving me crazy...

Comment: Have never seen an issue exactly like what you are describing. What if you load the CSS/JS/image files directly in your browser, do they show? All the time? Any exceptions in the logs? Did you try using an [HTTP monitor](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/monitoring-http-requests) like HttpScoop to see what happens when loading resources fails? Can you try clearing your caches? Restarting Tomcat?

Comment: If I point directly my browser to the css/js/images, sometimes it's ok, sometimes no. For example : http://localhost:8080/orbeon/config/theme/bootstrap.css returns the complete home page, not the css file. Cache clearing, restart tomcat doesn't help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with http monitoring, but I may have found something with TCPMon. When they are several GET and/or POST in the same request, some are not responded to. For example : the POST /orbeon/j_security_check is concatenated with a GET /.../icone_png => then the response contain the image only and the browser shows the icon instead of going to the "logged" page. Look like a server side problem, but don't know were to look at.

Comment: Mmh, I don't think there can be more than one GET or POST per request, but per open connection certainly. However, this might be related to authentication since you mention j_security_check. Can you try to make sure that the CSS etc. resources are *not* protected by form authentication?

Comment: Yes, you got it... It's related to form authentication. The erratic behavior came from the fact that some resources were already in the browser cache from other requests. I sought that invalidating the session was enough to avoid that problem, but it's not the case (Chrome seems to be pretty aggressive in that respect). Anyway, thanks **a lot** for your help !

Comment: Great, in that case I am moving my comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there can be more than one GET or POST per request, but per open connection certainly.

However, this might be related to authentication since you mention `j_security_check`. Can you try to make sure that the CSS and other resources are not protected by form authentication?

Comment: For short, that was the problem. Thanks :-)